# About switching application using Alt-Tab in MobaXterm when in a GUI tab

Tags: windows-10, vnc, user-interface, alt-tab, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm on Windows 10 to connect to a Ubuntu GNOME GUI desktop in cloud through VNC. An annoying feature of MobaXterm is that, the other part of MobaXterm obtains focus when I press Alt-Tab. Alt-Tab is the hot key to switch focus to other application in Windows, but when I press this key, the focus is still in MobaXterm but on some different control. This not only violates normal operation convention on Windows but also annoys me a lot because when I switch back from other applications, the focus is still on other controls of MobaXterm. Since I am not aware of it, the contents I intend to paste to ubuntu go to other part of MobaXterm and messes it up. I have to manually go to the GUI tab by mouse clicking. This, however, does not happen if I am in the tab containing command line of the host in cloud. So, do you know how to have MobaXterm behave the same way in both CLI tab and GUI tab, i.e, when I press Alt-Tab to switch out of the GUI tab, MobaXterm does not capture and override the behavior of Alt-Tab, but delivers it to the system so that I can switch to other applications in Windows, and get back to the GUI tab normally, instead of other part of MobaXterm? Thank you.